# How to switch paginator templates based on the prefix?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

## Using

Cake 3.2.4

## What's the situation currently

I have custom paginator templates that I have called from inside the AppView

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadHelper('Paginator', ['templates' => 'MyPluginForNormal.paginator-templates']);
}
```

How do I call up different paginator templates from different Plugins depending on the prefix?

## What I want

E.g. I want to be able to use the `MyPluginForAdmin.paginator-templates` whenever I am in the `/admin`

Is there a way to access the request object from AppView?

Comment: You could give it a try and check what `$this->request` returns...

Comment: i tried to do a `Cake/Log/Log::write('error', $this);` I saw the request inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside AppView object, it naturally contains the Request object.

When you do a

```
 \Cake/Log/Log::write('error', $this);
```

inside the `initialize` method, you should get back something like this:

```
[request] => Cake\Network\Request Object
    (
        [params] => Array
            (
                [plugin] => 
                [controller] => Products
                [action] => index
                [_ext] => 
                [pass] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [prefix] => admin
                [isAjax] => 
                [paging] => Array
```